# HTML JavaScript: using popup window?

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to create a popup window for changing the password.

The following is what I tried:

```
<form name="passwd" action="passwd.php" method="POST" >
Old Password:<input type="text" id="oldpwd" name="old_password" ><br>
New Password:<input type="text" id="newpwd" name="new_password" ><br>
Confirm Password:<input type="text" id="conpwd" name="confirm_password" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="Change password" width="5" id="cp">
</form>
```

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh you'll need to use AJAX to interact with your PHP script and replace the page's content with the server's response.

Comment: are you expecting the result without loading the page?

Comment: Thanks! I want to display the message on the main page itself. I don't  need to lost contents of the page at that time, the credentials must be checked in the server.

Comment: Again: What is the problem with your code? Why doesn't it work? What are you expecting it to do and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function Ajax(Form)
    {
     $.ajax({
       cache: false,
            type: 'post', 
            url: 'ChangePasswordPhpScript.php',
            data: $(Form).serialize(), 
            success: function(result) {  
           $('#info').html(result);
     }});
    return false;
    }
    </script>
<form onsubmit="return Ajax(this)">
<div id="info"></div>
<input type="text" name="email"><br/>
<input type="text" name="old"><br/>
<input type="text" name="new"><br/>
<input type="text" name="confirm"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Your comment works successfully. I also checked the link you gave me.

Comment: Please can I make it the password changer popup window smaller and formatting the result information?

Answer (score 0):

my way is something like this:

template.html:

```
<div class="errormsg">#ERROR#</div>
```

script.php:

```
<?php 
     $template = file_get_contents('template.html');
     if ($template !== NULL) {
         $error = array();
         if ($_POST['email'] == '') {
             $error[] = "The field email is empty";
         }

         $errorStr = '';
         foreach ($error as $message) {
             $errorStr .='<p>'.$message.'</p>';
         }

         $template = str_replace('#ERROR#',$errorStr,$template);
     }
```

When you want to use jquery than take a look at [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)